# call server-side method from client-side in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am calling a specific WebMethod from client side like this:

```
function openSmallPopup(int) {
        PageMethods.GetTenantInfo(int, OnGetMessageSuccess, OnGetMessageFailure);
        return 'I need here to return the result';
    }

    function OnGetMessageSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
        alert(result);
    }
```

Well, the result is successfully displayed in `OnGetMessageSuccess`. The single problem is that I really need to return that result in the initial `openSmallPopup` method...Do you guys know any way to do this?

Comment: Simply call openSmallPopup( result ) from OnGetMessageSuccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to that?? If you really want to do that then have to call initial function from OnGetMessageSuccess with result parameter and modify signature of initial function.

```
function openSmallPopup(int,result) {
    if(arguments.length === 1){
    PageMethods.GetTenantInfo(int, OnGetMessageSuccess, OnGetMessageFailure);
    }else if (arguments.length === 2){
      //use result here
    }
    return 'I need here to return the result';
}

function OnGetMessageSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
    alert(result);
    openSmallPopup(0,result);
}
```

But in practice i would rather take out that code from openSmallPopup into seperate function and call it in callback.